# Desaturated blue using CIELAB or CIE LCH

Tags: colors, cielab

Using http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=CALC#Result, if I start with a maximum-value, fully saturated blue by entering 0, 0, 0 with the "RGB 0-255" option, then I get the following for L*CH…

```
CIE-L*CH   =   32.303  133.816  306.287
```

When I run that in reverse, then I get the same blue that I started from — just as I expected. When I then try reducing the C* value, I would expect to see a desaturated blue, but instead, the result appears both desaturated and significantly shifted toward purple. The more I reduce the C* value, the farther toward purple it appears.

When I try the same thing using L*ab and shrink a* and b* by a common fraction, I get the same kind of result.

I presume that I am simply misunderstanding something about how these schemes are suposed to work. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I think that I understand this now. The L*ab colorspace is intended to represent equal amounts of perceptible change as equal spatial distances. That is accomplished by applying non-linear transformations to the XYZ colorspace axes, so as a result, a change directly toward or away from the black-white axis will not necessarily preserve hue.